# Android: Navigation Back using same activity with toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have an `activity` with differents `layouts`. Every time I want to go from one layout to another I use the `Visibility` property.
But I have a `toolbar` and I don't know how to set the navigation back because I have always the same activity.

In a normal situation with more activities I would use the property `android:parentActivityName`, but in this situation I can't because is the same activity.

Part of my code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- SIGN-IN SCREEN -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/screen_sign_in" style="@style/LLScreen">
    <TextView style="@style/GameTitle" />
    <TextView style="@style/GameBlurb" />

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton android:id="@+id/button_sign_in"
        style="@style/SignInButton" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- MAIN SCREEN -->
(...)
```

Code of the visibility I use to change screen:

```
void switchToScreen(int screenId) {
        // make the requested screen visible; hide all others.
        for (int id : SCREENS) {
            findViewById(id).setVisibility(screenId == id ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Then you have to implement your own screen stack, every time before switchToScreen you push the screenId to the stack, and override onBack, to pop the id to switchToScreen.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that your method of showing "screens" is unconventional. Unlike the normal approaches of using Activities or Fragments, you're simply toggling View visibilities which doesn't have any built-in history for what's been shown.

So, your only solution for this approach is to build your own cache of what's been shown.

This is easily done with any data type, like a `List`. For this answer, I'll use a `List` as an example.

So first, create an instance of a `List` to store the history of your screens inside of the `Activity`:

```
List<Integer> listOfScreens = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Next, make sure to add to this list when you switch screens:

```
listOfScreens.add(screenId);
switchToScreen(screenId);
```

This way, you'll add the new screen to the list and then switch to the proper screen.

Finally, in your Navigation Up and `onBackPressed()` code, simply remove the last screen on the list and switch again.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    listOfScreens.remove(listOfScreens.size()-1);
    switchToScreen(listOfScreens.get(listOfScreens.size()-1));
}
```

You'll remove the last item in the list which is the current screen, then switch the visibility back to the previous screen.

I've shown the code to do this in the `onBackPressed()` method, so do the same for your Up Navigation in your ToolBar.